# Create personality quiz

Tags: quiz

i'm looking for solution on how to create personality quiz. The Quiz module doesn't have an option to label answers - I need to find the most popular label checked and not the total amount of points.

It could be like this: 2 questions, 3 answers each. Each answer for each question has labels: "label one", "label two" and "label three" and they are randomized. I answer both questions and get "label two=2", which is the most popular label and therefore I am forwarded to node2 with some description.

Is it possible to do this with forms?

Answer (score 1):

The [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module would work for you. It gives you a nice interface to fetch the results so you can do some meaningful post analysis on your results too.

Comment: it doesn't look like it would be possible to create actions depending on the answer - if it would be possible, i could redirect the person to particular node depending on his answer result, but it is not possible to do with webform.

Comment: You can use Webform module, Rules module, Webform_rules module all together to create what to do automatically after submission on different answers.

Answer (score -1):

Someone wrote a great module for it

[Personality Test](https://www.drupal.org/project/personality-test)

> This module allows you to easily create a personality test that visitors can take.
>
> After you installed it a new node type becomes available, when you create a node of this type you can add questions and their possible answers; you can also define a score for each answer.